# Scrapy CrawlProcess crawl() function sometimes hangs indefinitely

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-selenium

I'm using CrawlPrcoess to run a scrapy spider with a selenium downloader. Most of the time the code works as expected but sometimes it hangs indefinitely after executing the crawl() function.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(project_settings)
process.crawl(MySpider, urls = urls) #This is where it hangs (but most of the time works fine)
process.start()
```

It's not throwing any exceptions so I'm trying to understand how to debug it.
Also, is it possible to setup a timeout exception for the crawl() function?

**UPDATE**

I was able to setup **spider_idle** signal. The signal is being configured properly but it's still not being executed. I guess this is not the proper signal for this task.

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    print("-- Initiating signals from_crawler function")
    spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.handleSpiderIdle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
    return spider
```

And below is the signal function but it's not being called.

```
    def handleSpiderIdle(self,spider):
       '''Handle spider idle event.'''  
       print(f'\nSpider idle: {spider.name}. Restarting it... ')
```

**UPDATE 2**

the code hangs specifically in **start_requests** function

```
    def start_requests(self):
    print("-- Initial Request Started --") #This print statement is not being executed
    yield SeleniumRequest(
        url=self.start_urls[0],
        callback=self.parse,
        wait_time=2,
    )
    print("-- Initial Request Passed --")
```